# Laravel UpdateExistingPivot doesn't update but at the same time doesn't fail

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have many to many relationships between Books and Members

I am retrieving all members using `Books->members()->get` and then decoding it to json. After that I am running a foreach loop

```
foreach($books as $id=>$book){
   $books->members()->updateExistingPivot($book->pivot->member_id, ['used' => 'false]
}
```

But it doesn't update the existing record even thou it finds it. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can you show dd($book), and your model? I think you just need to use like this:

    
      `foreach($books as $id=>$book){
           $book->members()->updateExistingPivot($book->member_id, ['used' => 'false]
        }`

Comment: It gives me Undefined property: stdClass $member_id @LuongPs

Comment: sorry did you book model has declare: 

     `public function members(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class, 'book_member', 'book_id', 'member_id')->withPivot('used');
    }`